# Proof verification: sequential definition of limits of functions implies $\epsilon - \delta$ definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Let $f$ be a function defined on a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$, let $a$ be a real number that is the limit of some sequence in $S$, and let $L$ be a real number. Let lim $n \rightarrow a $ along $S$ of $f(x) = L $ be defined as: "For every sequence $(x_n)$ in $S$ with limit $a$, we have lim $n \rightarrow \infty $ along $S$ of $f(x_n) = L $."

Using this sequential definition I am trying to prove:
lim $n \rightarrow a $ along $S$ of $f(x) = L $ implies:

for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x \in S$ and $| x -a |< \delta$ imply $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Is this valid?

"Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then for some $x_n$, there exists $N$ s.t. $ n > N \implies |f(x_n) - L| < \epsilon$.
Let $\delta = | f^{-1}(x_n) - a |$.
Then $|x_n - a| < \delta \implies |f(x_n) - L | < \epsilon$."

EDIT in response to Celio's comment.

"Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then for some sequence $x_n$, there exists $N$ s.t. $ n> N \implies |f(x_n) - L| < \epsilon$.
Let $\delta =$ min {$| f^{-1}(x_{N+1}) - a |$}.
Then $|x_n - a| < \delta \implies |f(x_n) - L | < \epsilon$."

Here I mean take the min of the distance of each preimage of $x_{N+1}$ from $a$. (Not the inverse).

I would really value any additional feedback!

Comment: This is not correct. To begin with, $f$ may not be bijective, so $f^{-1}(x_n)$ may be not defined.

Comment: @CélioAugusto Thank you. That makes sense. Related to this, I saw a proof where $f$ is not guaranteed to be bijective, but the inverse was used. So I wonder why in the below case it is allowed. The proof was that "If E is a connected subset of S, then f(E) is a connected subset of S*" (In this case we are given that f is a continuous map from S to S*.). The proof uses $f^{-1}$. Is it assumed we can somehow restrict the domain of a continuous function so it is bijective?

Comment: This is what I was referring to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226792/why-can-we-take-f-1-in-this-proof-that-continuous-functions-preserve-connec but actually it uses preimages, not the inverse proper as I thought

Comment: There is a nuance between an inverse function and the inverse of a function... or so I gathered from an interaction I had with a very reputable user on this site. In your case, $f^{-1}$ probably denoted $f^{-1}(X)=\{y:x\in X,f(y)=x\}$

Comment: There is no need to mess with inverse functions. The limit of a sequence and the limit of a function are similar notions but they do have different definitions; there is no need to conflate the two, and doing so rigorously requires more trouble than it's worth - or so I imagine, at first glance

Comment: To prove that sequential continuity$\Rightarrow$ continuity, you need the Axiom of Choice (or at least axiom of countable choice).

Comment: "Let lim $n \rightarrow a $ along $S$ of $f(x) = L $ be defined as: ..." This is pretty bad notation.

Comment: @zhw Thank you for the feedback! Excited to learn about improving my notation. Would love to hear any specific recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the statement "Let $\delta = min\{|f^{-1}(x_{N + 1}) - a|\}"$ is not clear enough. It may be that $f^{-1}(x_{N + 1}) = \emptyset$.

In your proof, there's an assumption that you can take N to be uniform across all sequences in S that converges to a. This is something you have to prove and you have to show that $\delta$ as defined is positive.

Also what you're trying to show is: for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that if $x \in S$ and $|x - a| \leq \delta$ then $|f(x) - L| \leq \epsilon$. But what you end up showing is: "$|x_{n} - a| \leq \delta \implies |f(x_{n}) - L| \leq \epsilon$ for large n, but it's not clear what the sequence $(x_{n})$ is.

Usually this statement is proven with a proof by contradiction. It may be easier to attempt it that way. Assuming that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \not = L$, then there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$, there exists an $x \in S$ such that $|f(x) - L| > \epsilon$ and $|x - a| \leq \delta$. Hence, for the sequence $\delta_{n} = 1/n$ for all $n \geq 1$, we get a sequence of $(x_{n}) \subset S$ that converges to a but $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_{n}) \not = L$.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful feedback @Mike! I understand each of these comments except for the first part where it's possible $f^{-1}(x_{N+1}) = \emptyset $.  $x_n$ is a sequence with limit $a$. Could you clarify or provide an example? Thanks again!

Comment: The sequence $(x_{n})$ is in S, which is the domain of the function. However, there's no guarantee that $x_{N + 1}$ is in the image of $f(x)$.