# Why can we take $f^{-1}$ in this proof that continuous functions preserve connectedness?

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

Here is a Ross proof from Elementary Analysis:

Theorem: Consider metric spaces $(S,d)$, $(S^*,d^*)$, and let $f: S \rightarrow S^*$ be continuous. If $E$ is a connected subset of $S$, then $f(E)$ is a connected subset of $S^*$.

Proof: Assume $f(E)$ is not connected in $S^*$.Then there exist open sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ in $S^*$ such that

$(f(E) \cap V_1) \cap (f(E) \cap V_2) = \emptyset$

$f(E) = (f(E) \cap V_1) \cup (f(E) \cap V_2) $

$f(E) \cap V_1 \neq \emptyset$

$f(E) \cap V_2 \neq \emptyset$

Let $U_1 = f^{-1}(V_1)$ and $U_2 = f^{-1}(V_2)$. Then $U_1$ and $U_2$ are open sets in $S$ that separate $E$ as in Definition 22.1(a) [Note, this is just the 4 requirements listed above given as a definition of disconnectedness]. Thus $E$ is not connected, a contradiction.

My question is, why are we allowed to assume $f$ has an inverse in this proof?

Comment: You need to go back to the beginning and learn notation. This is the *preimage* or *inverse image*.

Comment: Using $f^{-1}$ for preimages is a source of misunderstandings. I tend to use $f^\to$ for direct images and $f^\gets$ for preimages. Here $f^{-1}(V)$ means $\{x\in S:f(x)\in V\}$, which I denote instead by $f^\gets(V)$.

Comment: I have to admit, that i never thought about it but using $f^{\leftarrow}$ for the preimage is actually a really good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What *are not* allowed. Here, $f^{-1}(V)$ is the preimage of $V$, that is$$\{x\in S\mid f(x)\in V\},$$not the image of $V$ under $f^{-1}$ (although they are the same if $f$ is injective).